# Loading data from local JSON file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Using breakpoint I found out that every object is being initialized but the dictionary value is `nil`. Is there anything wrong with the syntax?

```
NSString *fileResource = @"albums";
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileResource ofType:@"rtf"];
NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
NSURL *localFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSData *contentOfLocalFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localFileURL];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentOfLocalFile options:0 error:nil];
```

The JSON file look like this

```
{
    "Albums": [{
        "Title": "Album 1",
        "Desc": "Description",
        "images": ["http://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/6391580/il_fullxfull.340668108.jpg", "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/6515756/il_fullxfull.330077675.jpg", "http://www.betterphoto.com/uploads/processed/0724/0706140402101moore_5-2.jpg"]
    }, {
        "Title": "Album 2",
        "Desc": "Description",
        "images": ["http://www.betterphoto.com/uploads/processed/0724/0706140402101moore_5-2.jpg", "http://www.artinnaturephotography.com/images/large/06012008_001.jpg",
            "http://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/6391580/il_fullxfull.340668108.jpg", "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/6515756/il_fullxfull.330077675.jpg", "http://www.betterphoto.com/uploads/processed/0724/0706140402101moore_5-2.jpg"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Use the `error` property from the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method and see what the error is.

Comment: add NSError *error;  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentOfLocalFile options:0 error:error];  It will show the error what it is.

Comment: @rmaddy It is showing The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: Then fix your JSON file so it is valid JSON. BTW - why are you trying to treat an RTF file as a JSON file? They are two completely different types of files.

Comment: @rmaddy can u tell me how to do that. Should I just rename the extension as .json?

Comment: That's a start. But that won't fix the contents of the file. Visit http://json.org to learn what the valid syntax is.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks got it.

Comment: @Rishab use json file, you are using `rtf` instead `json` file. create json file and then your code will work.

Comment: i agree @rmaddy thats what i said create json file it includes valid data also :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this i should work you are using rtf instead of json

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"albums" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];

    NSError *readerror;

    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&readerror];
```